# How to customize tabview in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How can i dock my Tabview items to the left of the screen like in the image below?

[image]
**This is how my layout looks like currently.**

```
<TabView dock="left" tabsBackgroundColor="red" selectedIndex="1" selectedColor="#FF0000" iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal" sdkExampleTitle sdkToggleNavButton>
    <StackLayout tabsBackgroundColor="red" *tabItem="{ iconSource: 'res://ic_ham'}" >
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Home'}">
            <ns-home></ns-home>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Bookings'}">
            <ns-booking></ns-booking>
    </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

**Resulting layout**

[image]

Comment: Create Layout for that instead of tab view and provide styles to look similar to it.

Comment: how to handle gesture in that case?

Comment: Gesture by you mean swipe to change tabs?

Comment: yes, how do i handle that?

Comment: https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/gestures

Answer (score 5):

It may be a bit of overkill for your needs, but what I've found simplest for us was to change the tab buttons to be fully designable and customizable by disabling the current buttons and the add new tab buttons.

```
<StackLayout class="grid-tab-view" columns="*,100,100,100,*" ios:rows="auto, auto" android:rows="auto, *">
    <label row="0" col="1" class="tab-button" text="Tab1" (tap)="switchTabByIndex(0)" [ngClass]="{'selected': tabSelectedIndex===0}"></label>
    <label row="0" col="2" class="tab-button" text="Tab2" (tap)="switchTabByIndex(1)" [ngClass]="{'selected': tabSelectedIndex===1}"></label>
    <label row="0" col="3" class="tab-button" text="Tab3" (tap)="switchTabByIndex(2)" [ngClass]="{'selected': tabSelectedIndex===2}"></label>
    <TabView colSpan="5" row="1" col="0" #tabView class="tab-view" [(ngModel)]="tabSelectedIndex" (loaded)="onTabsLoaded()" (selectedIndexChanged)="onTabSwitch($event)">
      <StackLayout class="tab" *tabItem="{title: 'Tab1'}">
          <Label text="tab1 body"></Label>
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout class="tab" *tabItem="{title: 'Tab2'}">
          <Label text="tab2 body"></Label>
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout class="tab" *tabItem="{title: 'Tab3'}">
          <Label text="tab3 body"></Label>
      </StackLayout>
    </TabView>
</StackLayout>
```

And in code:

- Add tap event handlers for when button selected and give it a custom selected class (for styling)
- Hide the default tab buttons using the tabs loaded event:

```js
onTabsLoaded(): void{
    let tabViewElement = <TabView>this.tabView.nativeElement;
    if (tabViewElement && tabViewElement.android) {
        tabViewElement.android.removeViewAt(0);
    } else {
        tabViewElement.ios.tabBar.hidden = true;
    }
};
```

and with a bit of css, our result:

[image: Custom nativescript tabs]

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: This is not what i am looking for, i just want to reduce the width of my Top tab view so that it doesnt spread to the entire screen

Comment: This could be a solution for you in case you do not find how to do a simple shift to left.
if you'll find a simpler solution do share.

P.S could it perhaps be possible to add a third tab, make it disabled and hidden? if so that might bring the result you wanted